# Why receive() method doesn't receive data from client?

Tags: java, network-programming

I wrote small client-server application. It should send one string from client to server and server should show it on console. But server waits for data all time. It looks like data don't come to server. What did i wrong?

```
public class UDPClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress IPAdress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        sendData = sentence.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAdress, 4445);
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}

public class UDPServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(4445);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        while(true) {
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are both the server and the client in main methods?

Comment: Where should they be? Sorry, I'm newbie to network programming.

Comment: @Stultuske Providing two classes with main methods makes this question an _excellent_ MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example; +1 for this). I first read the code and didn't see the error. So I got curios. I created two empty classes in my IDE an pasted the main methods. Within 30 seconds I reproduced the issue. That's great. And after a very short investigation with WireShark I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to actually send the package over the socket.

Simply add

```
clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
```

just before

```
clientSocket.close();
```

in `UDPClient.main()` and everything will work.

Comment: Where should be client and server, if not in main? In threads?

Comment: I personally prefer to scribble little concepts inside tests. If tests are concerned with network programming and you have client and server in one project there is nearly no other way then to implement client and server in threads. But if you are just playing around with some concepts your approach is also fine.